# Terminal Server 2008 - Shared/Default User Profile?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services, profile

We are testing a Windows Server 2008 Standard Terminal Services mini-farm set up in VMWare to help manage a single application remote deployment. This application stores a LOT of settings in the per-user registry so we lose a lot of the benefits of terminal services (centralized app management, less user headaches, etc.) if we have the users log in as themselves. So, we have a single domain login (termsvc) that all the users login with. This feels bad for obvious reasons.

So, is there a way we can install (and more importantly: configure and continue to upgrade) this app ONCE and then "share" the registry with all the users so they can log in as themselves instead of all sharing a single login? Maybe have a single terminal services profile that these users share? What are our options here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps I am over-simplifying, but ...

1- ID the registry changes -- see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/23500/keeping-track-of-changes-to-a-system-during-software-patch-installation) for suggestions on how to do so.  Edit out the "machine" section of the changes.

2- Use GPO or login script to publish those changes as each user logs on.

Comment: This is a better idea than my "hack" answer, but I thought I'd give an alternative perspective for fun. *smile*

Comment: @evan .. thanks.  It is kind of a hack as well.  I suspect there is a TS way to publish an app just as they would like, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: This is probably the way to go. Too bad implementing "ID the registry changes" isn't easier... Ugh. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with standard roaming user profiles and I have no reason to believe this won't work with a TS roaming profile. I'd love to hear what you find, though:

- Assign a roaming profile to a test user.
- Logon as the test user and prepare the profile as you'd like it to be.
- Logoff and logon as an "Administrator" on some box.
- Using RegEdit's "Load Hive" functionality, attach the "NTUSER.DAT" from the test user's roaming user profile to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\somethingorother" on some box.
- Modify the permission on HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\somethingorother to include "Users - Full Control". Detach the hive.
- Rename the "NTUSER.DAT" file in the test user's roaming user profile to "NTUSER.MAN".
- Alter the permission on the test user's roaming user profile directory such that all the users to share the profile can read the folder and files (preferrably by using a group).
- Assign the test user's roaming profile folder to one of the other affected users as a TS roaming profile.
- Logon as the affected user with the TS roaming profile specified. Verify that they get the specially-prepared environment and that changes they make are not propogated back to the roaming user profile.

That should do what you want. I haven't done this little hack in a few years-- hopefully no service packs or other code changes "broke" the functionality. Give it a try and see.